# repository and dataModel to return in specific cases

Tags: model, repository, datamodel

I'm using webforms without any ORM, so I have a hard time to understand how to deal with data models in situation when I need specific fields that are not directly related to an object.

For example I have the stores table, and in one page I need to display all stores with their owner data, in another one - all stores with their billing information, and so on. Having a repository class, what should it return ? A dynamic object ? I cannot create a model for each case in particular,
Also, implementing a method for each of this cases in particular will result in a lot of methods and it will be hard to understand what's happening.

Could someone give me a hint, or some information, to understand how to deal with such cases ?
Sorry if my question is not to specific..